# Calculating proportions of land use per grid cell in R

Tags: r, glm

I want to perform a binomial GLM with my data, which is based on the proportions of land use type per used or unused cell on a map. With used being: where an owl was heard an unused being: where no owl was heard. I know have two polygon layers, one containing all the used areas and their land type and one containing all the unused areas and their land types.

I am unsure how to perform this analysis in R. I probably first need to put a grid over the layers, to divide the maps in cells that are either used or unused. Then I need to calculate the proportion of land use type per grid cell.

Are there any packages I could use for this? How would you go about this?

Comment: there are many packages dealing with spatial data. often used ones are `sp`, `sf`, `raster` and `stars`. this list is by no means exhaustive and what libraries (or combination of libraries) you want to use is up to you. your question is not really about programming but about how to do your analysis. i am not sure SO is the correct platform for it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have a tip for what would be the right platform for me?

Comment: that depends on your data. personaly i prefer the `sf` (simple features) way of doing things as i find it more intuitive than other packages. still without knowing your data/data structure i can not really give a recommendation.

Comment: Oh no I meant which platform to ask my question on, but thank you! Well I now have all my data in QGIS. Two polygon layers (one with all the used area/area where owls were heard, one with all the unused area/area where owls weren't heard) of my study area divided into 12 land use categories. I want to grid these polygon layers and then calculate the proportion of land use per grid cell.

Comment: Oh, well I think reading papers on similar topics and following their methodology will be better than asking such a non-specific question in any forum. here (on SO) we can help with error messages or code improvements but you will not find anyone doing the concept (code layout) for you. same with mathoverflow and similar sites that certainly will help with math related questions but not with creating your study for you